# I'm traying to create a ResNet model for time series forecasting, I got always the same prediction which is "1.0", don't know why?

Tags: prediction, forecasting, resnet

I'm traying to create a ResNet model for time series forecasting, I got always the same prediction which is "1.0", don't know why?
def create_res_net():

```
    inputs = Input(shape=(50, 1))
    num_filters = 5
    
    t = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
    t = Conv1D(kernel_size=18, strides=1, filters=num_filters, padding="same")(t)
    t = relu_bn(t)
    
    num_blocks_list = [2, 5, 5, 2]
    for i in range(len(num_blocks_list)):
        num_blocks = num_blocks_list[i]
        for j in range(num_blocks):
            t = residual_block(t, downsample=(j==0 and i!=0), filters=num_filters)
        num_filters *= 2
    
    t = AveragePooling1D(2)(t)
    t = Flatten()(t)
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(t)
    
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
model = create_res_net()
# save model after each epoch
model.fit(x=X, y=y_train,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

Comment: can you offer more information? What exactly is the problem you're solving? What is the dataset? Can you give us training logs?

Comment: time series forecasting, the dataset:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = data.split_data()
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 50

# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
# X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))
X = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))

Epoch 1/10
21/21 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 480633.5938 - accuracy: 0.0030

Comment: time series forecasting, the dataset:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = data.split_data()
X_train shape is (665, 50, 1)
y_train shape is (665, 1) 

Epoch 1/10
21/21 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 480633.5938 - accuracy: 0.0030